# Activity: getIntent() in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) varies when savedInstanceState not null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here is my problem.

- Activity B is started by Activity A by `startActivityForResult`,
- Activity A passed a String array in the intent by `intent.putExtra(TAG)`,
- Activity B get the String array in `onCreate()` by `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(TAG)`.

It went well most of the time.
When the issue happened, the String array get in Activity B is different from usual, it is shorter than before.

At that time parameter, `savedInstanceState` passed to Activity B's `onCreate` is not null, which means Activity B is doing a recovery from the previous state.

How does this happen? Is it not safe to get data from `getIntent()` when `savedInstanceState` is not null?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What other "extras" are in the `Intent`? If the `Activity` is being restarted it means that Android has killed off the process in the background and the user later returns to the app causing a new OS process to be created. In this case, the `Intent` will be reconstructed from its serialized form. Probably the problem occurs then.

Comment: To answer your question though, yes, it is always safe to call `getIntent()`, regardless of the situation.